# How can i disable a button when the model is not updated?

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jface

In my UI i have  2 text field and and 2 buttons .I am using jface data binding to bind the text field and i am doing the validation  and depending on the validation success  the model is updated other wise it will not.I want my button to respond accordingly .Like if my model is not updated than i want to disable my button.One more  thing that i do anot want to do hard coding .so is there any way to that without hard coding.

In other way I want to bind a button to text field so that when the text field has some unwanted value than the button should be disabled .In the other way i am doing data binding on text field  which will take care when the text field does not have proper value than it will not update its model.Then i want to disable the button when the value is not proper can i do that.Any pointer on this helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that I have to observe the enable/disable property of the button and bind it with the current emf databinding context. Detail of the function which I have used is given below:

```
void bindEnablementButtonToValidationStatus(Button button, EMFDataBindingContext ctx) {

    IObservableValue buttonEnable = SWTObservables.observeEnabled(button);
    IObservableValue validationStatus = new AggregateValidationStatus(
            ctx.getValidationRealm(),
            ctx.getBindings(), 
            AggregateValidationStatus.MAX_SEVERITY);

    ctx.bindValue(buttonEnable, validationStatus, 
            new EMFUpdateValueStrategy(
                    UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_NEVER), 
                    new EMFUpdateValueStrategy().setConverter(
                            new Converter(IStatus.class, Boolean.TYPE) {
                                public Object convert(Object fromObject) {
                                    return new Boolean(((IStatus)fromObject).isOK());
                                }
                            }));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of below listener. Add listener to your `Observable`

```
 org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.IValueChangeListener
```